# Problema com porcentagem de valores monetários e arredondamento

Tags: c#, matemática, .net-core, valor-monetário, asp-net-core

Como manter valores monetários com apenas 2 casas decimais ao realizar operações de percentual? Exemplo:

- Valor total: R$ 377,17
- Divisões em percentual: 33%, 33% e 34%

Problema: a soma do valor das parcelas não é igual ao valor total.

Código:

```cs
public static decimal Calcular(decimal valor, int percentual)
{
    var fator = percentual / 100M;
    return decimal.Round(valor * fator, 2);
}
```

Teste:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(new[] { 39, 60, 1 }, 0.12)]
[InlineData(new[] { 33, 33, 34 }, 377.17)]
public void DeveCalcularPercentualComSucesso(int[] percentuais, decimal valorTotal)
{
    var resultados = new decimal[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < percentuais.Length; i++)
        resultados[i] = Percentual.Calcular(valorTotal, percentuais[i]);

    var soma = resultados.Sum();

    soma.Should().Be(valorTotal);
}
```

```cs
Expected soma to be 377.17M, but found 377.18M.
```

Comment: Qual é o teu problema? ele está retornando valores inteiros ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O cálculo está sendo feito de forma conceitualmente errada. Não é só problema de arredondamento. Embora raro, só não arredondar pode dar diferença do mesmo jeito porque em um ponto lá no fim da precisão pode dar uma diferença mínima em alguns casos (não vai acontecer quando os percentuais são inteiros).

Na verdade, eu acho que este método ainda está conceitualmente errado porque ele atende uma definição conceitualmente errada. Está errado e pode ser até ilegal em casos específicos parcelar um valor desta forma com percentuais arbitrários (em alguns casos pode). Em geral o mais correto é dizer o número de parcelas e o critério do que fazer com a diferença que em muitos casos ocorrerá. Esta diferença costuma ser de 1 ou poucos centavos.

O critério pode ser colocar na primeira, na última, se for mais que um centavo colocar nas primeiras o mais distribuído possível, ou nas últimas, e pode até detalhar o que fazer quando houver diferença até na distribuição, embora raro pode até dizer posições específicas, em alguns casos tem legislação regulando isso. Em alguns casos aceita-se diferença para mais ou para menos por legislação ou convenção própria, mas neste caso específico não é o que deseja. Então este método é só uma base de como resolver, note que está fixo que a diferença fica na última.

O mais correto seria validar se a soma dos percentuais dá 100, mas preferi deixar isso a cargo do programador fazer certo já que você costuma fazer testes de unidade. Uma das vantagens deste tipo de teste é que se ele for feito certo evita custo de performance para validar o argumento. Testes assim tem desvantagens também que ninguém fala, mas isto é outro assunto.

Empresas e programadores em geral não entendem como as rotinas de sua operação devem funcionar e estão sempre correndo risco de multas governamentais, contratuais ou ter outros problemas.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var item in CalculaPercentuais(377.17M, new decimal[] { 33.0M, 33.0M, 34.0M })) WriteLine(item);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<decimal> CalculaPercentuais(decimal valor, IEnumerable<decimal> percentuais) {
        var valores = new List<decimal>();
        foreach (var percentual in percentuais) valores.Add(decimal.Round(valor / 100.0M * percentual, 2));
        var soma = 0.0M;
        for (var i = 0; i < valores.Count - 1; i++) soma += valores[i];
        valores[valores.Count - 1] = valor - soma;
        return valores;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aMqW1u). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bdJhZR). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/PercentilExact.cs).

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela explicação. Estou tentando justamente evitar distorções nos cálculos. Incluir a diferença em um dos elementos tem sido a melhor saída por enquanto.

Comment: Só preste atenção em todo o texto porque não sei nem se essa forma é a correta. Agora você consegue votar em tudo no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

O problema está no arredondamento. Você está calculando os percentuais e arredondando para 2 casas decimais e depois somando os arredondamentos e isto causa a diferença.

Para que a soma das parcelas seja exatamente igual ao valor inicial, você não deveria arredondar o valor, este arredondamento, se necessário, deveria ser feito apenas no fim.

Segue exemplo abaixo com o valor de 377,17:

377,17 * 33% = 124,4661     - Arredondando com `decimal.Round` fica 124,47

377,17 * 34% = 128,2378     - Arredondando com `decimal.Round` fica 128,24

124,4661 + 124,4661 + 128,2378 = 377,17

124,47   + 124,47   + 128,24   = 377,18

Caso você deseje mostrar o valor arredondado para o usuário, você pode exibir o valor arredondado mas deveria guardar este valor sem estar arredondado para que no final a soma fique exata.